# Extract 3 pieces of information from a string

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I'm looking to pull information from a pasted string in Google Sheets.
For example, the user will paste something like `Blue (010,110)`
My columns are like so

```
     A                 B         C      D
1    String            Colour    X      Y
2    Blue (010,110)    Blue      010    110
3    Cyan (011,111)    Cyan      011    111
```

I have no issue with the colour `B`, as shown

`=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-9))`

But I'm struggling to get the X and Y values for `C` and `D`

Can anyone help me with the method here?

Here is the furthest I have gotten, but I have one issue with the length of the colour (yellow wouldn't work). My other issue is that I'm just recieving `)` as a result no matter what I put in.
`=IF(ISBLANK(A11),"",MID(A11,(LEFT(LEN(A11),3)),3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for cell C2 should be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",MID(A2,LEN(A2)-7,3))
```

and for D2 it should be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",MID(A2,LEN(A2)-3,3))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do a single formula , actually also an array formula so you only have to ever add it once:

```
=arrayformula(if(istext(F3:F),REGEXEXTRACT(F3:F,"(\w+)\D+(\d+),(\d+)"),))
```

[image]

This basically creates capture groups around the patterns, so `\w+` means word (technically it means any alphanumeric character), followed by any `non-digit` which is `\D+` and then  the 2 digit capture groups: `\d+`

The capture groups effectively automatically push those matches to the adjacent cells, and the array formula repeats the formula all the way down as long at there is valid data present.

Comment: I really like this formula, but I'll leave it currently, as I may make changes, meaning the other forumlae will be easier to change than yours.